# Asterisk Register username with special character like "@"

Tags: asterisk, sip, freepbx

I am using a SIP provider that has provided me with a username like:

+1122233344@aaa.bb.com    (Note this is only the username part)

And has a numerical password. My Register string looks something like this:

+112223344@aaa.bb.com:123123@aaa.bb.com

But this is not working, as asterisk is only sending the first part +112223344 before the first @. My provider is adamant about having the full form of it. This is the first time I am facing this issue that is quite unusual for me. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Try it with quotes, like this:

```
"username":"password"@server
```